# Extract substring until whitespace in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this string:
**this http is a link**
I want to take everything that begins at http until the whitespace (it will be a different link each time).
Example: this http://www.google.com is a link (i want the http://www.google.com)
I tried the substring `substring(str.indexOf("http"),str.indexOf(" "));`
but it gets confused which whitespace to take.

Comment: Split on spaces into an array, loop the array until you find the element starts with http, then break out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the substring of x, starting at `http`, up until the first space after `http`:

```
x.substring(x.indexOf('http'),x.indexOf(' ', x.indexOf('http')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```js
var link = "i want http://www.google.com xxxx";
var st = link.indexOf('http');
alert(link.substring(st, st + link.substr(st, link.length).indexOf(' ')));
```

Comment: Works but you don't explain how it works,it's a bit confusing.